# Inversive geometry: is it possible to point-invert a Euclidean space and not produce a hyperbolic one?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, geometric-topology, inversive-geometry

Is it possible to point-invert a Euclidean space and not produce a hyperbolic one?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what point-inverting means?

Comment: Point inversion is usually called "point reflection," but I use the common alternate because I can't visualize the transformation as a reflection, because it's reflection off of  a hyperdimensional mirror. That just means "from one higher dimension.

It turns out I should have used circle inversion.

Answer (score 1):

Inversion is a transformation in Euclidean geometry. If a circle $C$  is given then all the points inside the circle  will be transformed to points outside of $C$ and vice versa. The points on the perimeter of $C$ will stay.

This way you don't get hyperbolic geometry.

However if you want to construct arcs of circles within $C$ that are perpendicular to $C$ then you will use inversion as a construction tool.

Now, you have arcs within $C$ but this is still not hyperbolic geometry. Further to all  said above you will have to appropriately define congruence between segments on these arcs within $C$.

Then you get to the Poincaré model of hyperbolic geomtry.

Comment: Thanx, Zoli!

Okay, I was talking about point inversion, which is fascinating! But never mind that. Circle inversion is the appropriate concept.

First of all, you're right. The inversion, which maps infinity in all directions to a point in the center, is Euclidean(!). But I only say that because the articles I should have  read before asking the question say so.  [contd...]

Comment: [...contd]
**Is it not hyperbolic because hyperbolic models map infinite space to a finite space, or because infinity has to be on the *edge* of a hyperbolic model, not the center?**

The thing is, what you get after inverting an infinite plane through a circle is a squished-flat, 2D pseudosphere, with infinity at a point in the center  instead of at the end of an infinitely-long horn. *But that flat manifold can be stretched back out into a 3D pseudosphere, which IS hyperbolic.*

So why isn't the squished version of the pseudosphere (identical to a circle inversion) also hyperbolic?